# React element is not appearing on screen

Tags: reactjs

trying to dynamically adding the elements in dom

```
{props.contactInfo.data &&
        props.contactInfo.data.map((contact, index) => {
          contact.contactRoles &&
            contact.contactRoles.map((r) => {
              const role = props.codeList[prop0].find(
                (c) => c.codeValue === r.contactRole
              );
              if (r.contactRole === "MAIN") {
                console.log(1)
                return (
                  <div>trial</div>
                );
              }
            }
            )

        })}
```

console is logging one but still element is not appearing on screen .

Comment: What is prop0 ?

Comment: you need to return the result of calling `contact.contactRoles.map(...)`

Comment: prop0 has been declared before and is available

Comment: `props.contactInfo.data.map` also need return something

Comment: @yousaf it worked , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change curly bracket `{}` to parenthesis `()` which means return.

```js
{
  props.contactInfo.data &&
    props.contactInfo.data.map((contact, index) => ( // change to parenthesis
      contact.contactRoles &&
        contact.contactRoles.map((r) => {
          const role = props.codeList[prop0].find(
            (c) => c.codeValue === r.contactRole
          );
          if (r.contactRole === "MAIN") {
            console.log(1)
            return ( <
              div > trial < /div>
            );
          }
        })
    )) // and here
}
```